# how could I implement an online test with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, webserver

I have a webpage with small javascript code that serves a test to students. But the test is actually hardcoded into the page, and I would like some sort of importing method in which the page when displayed can read the questions that would be in a text or xml document. I was thinking of using ajax, but ajax needs some sort of web server running in order to interpret the 'get' or 'post' method. Is there any way I could do this withot running a webserver.

here's html code

```js
var pos = 0,
  test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
  ["What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B"],
  ["What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C"],
  ["What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A"],
  ["What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C"]
];

function _(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

function renderQuestion() {
  test = _("test");
  if (pos >= questions.length) {
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;
    return false;
  }
  _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length;
  question = questions[pos][0];
  chA = questions[pos][1];
  chB = questions[pos][2];
  chC = questions[pos][3];
  test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "<br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " + chC + "<br><br>";
  test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}

function checkAnswer() {
  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      choice = choices[i].value;
    }
  }
  if (choice == questions[pos][4]) {
    correct++;
  }
  pos++;
  renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

```css
div#test {
  border: #000 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: If you don't have a webserver, where is the HTML coming from?

Comment: I know you don't want a server. But is cheating an issue? If so I would not have answers client side. And instead send their input to a server via an AJAX request to verify the answer. You would be surprised with how handy kids can be with "view source" or dev tools these days.

Comment: Get a server. Really. You could do all this with static content in an HTML5 app using local storage to seperate your logic from your data but you still need a server to deploy the app. Putting the logic serverside is a much simpler approach, reduces scope for cheating and there are los of free software packages that might meet your requirements without having to write any code.

Comment: I was planing on putting the html page on the server's share drive that is mapped to students computer, and have them click the page, of course this would serve the page in the browswer in the form of file:///server/page.html. then if the page needs to process any ajax request to a separate page to, lets say, load the questions into an array, it wouldn't work with 'get' or 'post' methods b/c there's not webserver..... how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

How about importing your questions and their answers in the page using something like

querystring could contain a set of parameters like timestamp parameter specifiying when the querystring was generated, 
a digital signature using md5

when returnJavaScript.html is requested. the file would contain a javscript function processing the querystring, and verifying that the timestamp is not too old. Then the rule woudl be that:
if there is no valid query string, the html file return nothing or basic useless information.
if the md5 signature is valid, but the timestamp has passed, return nothing again
if the md5 signature is valid, and the timestamp (time limit) is not passed, then return the javascript that you need for the question.

In that way it makes it a lot more difficult to get to see the answers.

Comment: could you point me to an example, I have an idea, but it would be easy if I see a live example of the script

Comment: I am afraid I do not have the time to provide a script for this - I wish I did - I was only sharing the idea, which I hope you can put into action.